# Уведомления с сайта в Telegram (нажатие на ссылку телефона)

Tags: telegram

Можно ли сделать уведомления на телеграмм ботв при нажатии на ссылку телефона, перехода с сайта в мессенджер (при нажатии кнопки на сайте)
На данный момент настроил телеграмм бота на отправку формы с сайта.